# How I can insert multiple records in one SQLite query?

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

I need insert multiple records in my DB SQLite.

I get an ArrayList with objects type "Nota", and I need insert this ArrayList completely.

My Object "Nota" has method getId and getTitle. So I can do arrayList_nota.get(Attribute) to get all attributes and insert.

My DB SQLite has: | ID | Title | Date | Text |

But I do not know if it is possible. And I do not know this query sintax. I need insert every position of array and her attributes.

How I can insert multiple records in one SQLite query?

Answer (score 0):

```
Insert into Nota (ID,Title,Date,Text) 
Select '1','LOTR 1','2010-01-01','Lord of The Rings 1'
union Select '2','LOTR 2','2010-02-01','Lord of The Rings 2'
union Select '3','Lotr 3','2010-03-01', 'Lord of the Rings 3';`
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a one sql statement solution.

```
try {
    // db is your SQLiteDatabase object.
    db.beginTransaction();
    for ( Nota n : arrayList_nota ) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put( ID, n.getId() );
        values.put( TITLE, n.getTitle() );
        values.put( DATE, n.getDate() );
        values.put( TEXT, n.getText() );
        db.insert( TABLE_NAME, null, values );
    }
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
} catch ( SQLiteException e ) {
    // handle your sqlite database exceptions.
} finally {
    db.endTransaction();
}
```